# fmt:setBundle not working properly in multiuser

Tags: java, jsp, localization, internationalization, jstl

**JSP** page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.commonapp.I18n.JspResourceBundle" var="lang" />    
<fmt:message key="Home" bundle="${lang}" />
```

**Java** classes:
Have two files 
`JspResourceBundle_fr_FR.class` and 
`JspResourceBundle.class extending ListResourceBundle`

**Scenario**: After application restart, if first login through user with French locale, then another user with English locale logs in via different browser. Both the users see the page in French.
If reverse the order, English user logs in followed by French user, both the user sees the page in English.

The first logged in user sets the bundle and for the second user it gets picked up from cache. I think it's because jsp code is compiled to `_jsp_service.class` with that bundle and stays in the memory.

Is there any way to fix this in jsp/jstl. Can successfully process the same by setting locale specific labels from java code. But the same should be achievable via simple jsp, if I'm not wrong.

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Where and how do you set the **locale**?

Comment: locale is set in login success handler. Other java code gives proper localized message [with ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationMessages") - the default locale for the session] irrespective of login order.